# Online Goal Manager

Tags: time-management, self-management, goals

I'm looking for a website that offers free goal management for simple tasks, in the shape of a to-do list. Something that can handle simple tasks with an option to "check" it and automatically archive and complex tasks that has several smaller tasks in it which could display a progress bar in the overview to help keep track of everything.

Do you happen to know any?

Comment: Hey Renan, welcome to the site. Is this question about personal goal tracking, or project management type goal tracking? (This site is exclusively for PM-related questions; it seems like your question is about personal goal management.)

Comment: Thank you! This question is about both actually. I'd use it to keep track of my progress at work and personal goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Task Freak, it is self hosted -- I like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something very simple for personal use, or something at work that is really just for you, and you use Gmail or Google Apps, you could use the "Tasks" feature in Gmail/Google Apps.

Look below Mail and Contacts on the top left in Gmail, and you'll see an embedded popup window, similar to a Google Talk Chat, that has space for you to enter tasks.

You can email the completed task list to yourself, which archives it in Gmail for later retrieval.

I will say that I wouldn't recommend this for large projects or projects where you're dealing with other people's tasks. this is simply something I'd suggest for personal use or for your own use at work.

Answer (score 1):

Try Team Task Manager.   I use it daily to track projects and tasks, very intuitive and no learning curve.  The website is here -  http://www.deskshare.com/team-task-management.aspx